# jQuery.datePicker stopped working while using 2 versions of jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use two versions of jQuery: 1.2 and 1.9.

I added to my Main.Master the lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl ("~/jquery-1.2.6.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl ("~/jquery-ui.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl ("~/jquery-1.9.1.min.js") %>"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $new = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

I use jquery.tinePicker in my application, and since I added the new jQuery I get the exception:

Unable to get property '_selectDay' of undefined or null reference

from the line:

```
function onclick()
{
jQuery.datepicker._selectDay(param,param,param,param);
}
```

I guess it is from the jQuery-ui file.
Any ideas how can I make it work?

Comment: Select one version to use only - and then see what error you get...

Comment: No errors.... It worked fine until I added:
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl ("~/jquery-1.9.1.min.js") %>"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $new = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

Comment: Remove it then. If you wish to use the 1.9.1 remove the 1.2.6, and the jquery-ui, then use the 1.9.1 and make a new jquery-ui from their site for the new version. You can not use two jquery versions like that Its a library, understand what is do and how is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points.

- Each **jQuery User Interface** is correctly work with **specific version** of jQuery
- You must use **only one** jQuery library (common sense).
- The [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) is used to change the `$` with `jQuery` and avoid conflicts with **other** libraries that also use the symbol `$`

So, what you have done here, you include the version 1.2.6, then the user interface for that version, then you overwrite it with 1.9.1 and then use the noConfict.

As results the user interface will not work, and who knows what other conflicts may exist.

If you wish to use the new version, remove the old and the old user interface.
Include only the new one, make a new user interface library file [from their site and incl due it also](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Comment: I can't remove the old version because jQuery don't have a backward compatibility and things stop working when I remove it.
I read it is possible to include 2 versions of jquery using noConflict: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ (although not recommended). I will check if it is possible to include 2 versions of jquery ui. Thanks anyways :)